# Add data after others data in JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hello fellow developers.

In order to create an automatic Drag n 'Drop function in PHP for uploading files, I am stuck in the data update after saving a first file. Indeed, I store in my database a JSON table which contains the name of the file, its path and also its type.

It looks something like this :

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "1",
        "path": "/files/project/customer1/pictures/",
        "type": "jpeg"
    }
}
```

[image]

However, if now I add another file, I can't find a solution to add it following my JSON structure.

I would like it to follow this logic:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "img1",
        "path": "/files/project/customer1/pictures/",
        "type": "jpeg"
    },

    "2": {
        "name": "img2",
        "path": "/files/project/customer1/pictures/",
        "type": "jpeg"
    }
}
```

Here is the condition I made.
I use the **MEDOO** library in PHP, hence the **update function**.

The **before function** retrieves everything after the "." so recover the file type.

```
<?php
if ($error == "") {
    echo $_FILES["$name"]["name"] . " a bien été téléchargé";
    $jsonOrig = '';
    $jsonOrig = $database->get($table, 'attachment', ['id' => $table_id]);
    $database->update(
        $table,
        ['attachment' => Core::jsonify(
            $jsonOrig,
            ['name' => $this->before('.', $_FILES["$name"]["name"]), 'path' => '/files/' . $path . '/', 'type' => $ext],
            1
        )],
        ['id' => $table_id]
    );
}
```

The **jsonify function** allows you to generate JSON automatically.

```
<?php
    public static function jsonify($jsonOrig = array(), $jsonAdd, $where = "")
    {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        if (!is_array($jsonOrig)) {
            $jsonOrig = json_decode($jsonOrig, true);
        }

        if (!is_array($jsonAdd)) {
            $jsonAdd = json_decode($jsonAdd, true);
        }

        if (empty($where)) $jsonOrig[] = $jsonAdd;
        else $jsonOrig[$where] = $jsonAdd;

        return json_encode($jsonOrig, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

Here is the function once used

```
// parameter one = input file name
// parameter two = The path where the file will be uploaded
// parameter three = table name database
// parameter four = id where add the json file in the database 
$Files->addFile('file', 'projets/client2/photos', 'articles', 54);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you get currently? an error? wrong data? You should try to parse existing JSON with `json_decode`, append the new entry then pass the whole thing to `Core::jsonify`. Also, what does represent the `"1"`/`"2"` as main keys in your object in the JSON? An id that you use elsewhere? If it's just a way to have ordered data, you should use a proper array instead (JSON structure `[ {...}, {...} ]`

Comment: Currently my data is being updated. However with each new file added, my old data is overwritten for the new ones, I would like to concatenate them. The primary key is used to identify each file so that it can then be retrieved elsewhere and displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third parameter to `Core::jsonify` is the "$where", meaning the key behind which you will store your new item in the array. If you pass `1` it will always store the value behind the same key, actually overriding your previously stored item. Remove this parameter and it will properly append to the array (what is done here `$jsonOrig[]` when key is missing PHP appends a new item).

```
<?php
if ($error == "") {
    echo $_FILES["$name"]["name"] . " a bien été téléchargé";
    $jsonOrig = '';
    $jsonOrig = $database->get($table, 'attachment', ['id' => $table_id]);
    $database->update(
        $table,
        ['attachment' => Core::jsonify(
            $jsonOrig,
            ['name' => $this->before('.', $_FILES["$name"]["name"]), 'path' => '/files/' . $path . '/', 'type' => $ext]
            //remove the ",1"
        )],
        ['id' => $table_id]
    );
}
```

If this doesn't work, it means that the `get` doesn't retreive properly existing data

Comment: Thank you for your help, I surely had to add this to debug a few days ago and I remembered more, but now it works perfectly thanks to you !